# Why does changing data directory for PostgreSQL 9.5 in Server 2008 lead to "directory does not exist"?

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, postgresql, file-permissions

I'm trying to migrate a PostgreSQL 9.5 database to a larger disk E on a Windows 2008 Server. After stopping the service I initially tried copying the the `data` folder to the new disk and then changed the PostgreSQL Service's executable path using

```
sc config postgresql-x64-9.5 binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\pg_ctl.exe\" runservice -N \"postgresql-x64-9.5\" -D \"E:\pg_db\data\" -w"
```

I changed the permissions on the `data` folder to include "Network Services" by right-clicking on the folder and going `Properties`. Under the `Security` Tab click "`Edit...`" and then "`Add...`". Type  "`Network Service`" and then click "`Check Names`" and then `OK`.

But when I hit Start in Services, the following error message appears under the Windows Event Viewer:

```
FATAL: data directory "E:/pg_db/data" does not exist.
```

I even tried creating a new data directory from the administrator `cmd` prompt using instructions [here](http://www.garretwilson.com/blog/2014/03/09/postgresql-management-windows.xhtml) but eventually got the same error.

I see [one of the answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/276634/change-data-path-for-postgresql) to the "Similar Questions" as I'm writing this is "It is easier if you reinstall Postgre and select data folder during install." That can't be the best we can do.

Comment: Have you seen this link?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596301/how-to-change-postgresql-data-directory

Comment: @user3137702, just tried that. I get `EDT FATAL:  data directory "E:/pg_db/data" does not exist` again

Comment: Also (since that didn't work), it's better to use `sc config ...` because that sets the right user for the postgres Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem while scanning through the [Running & Installing PostgreSQL On Native Windows Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Running_%26_Installing_PostgreSQL_On_Native_Windows#What_filesystem_permissions_does_PostgreSQL_require.3F)

> The PostgreSQL service account needs read permissions on all directories leading up to the service directory. It needs write permissions only on the data directory.

I had set the *write* permission on the `data` directory for `Network Service` but not the *read* permission on the directories above it.